# Develop GUI and logic in a team the right way?

Tags: java, mvc, interfaces, team, javafx

I am planning to start a small project with a friend. I will be developing the GUI using JavaFX in the MVC pattern and he will be responsible for the model/logic.

My question is: how can we achieve a save parallel developing, how do companies do that? Would we just write an interface for the model together, that specifies what functionality I will need in the controller and thus he has to implement?

Thx in advance.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This is not really something that you can try & error...

Comment: I wrote that my idea would be interfaces.

Comment: did you check [ask] page referred in prior comment? "Search, and research

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer _before_ asking..."

Comment: I didn't find anything on how to develop in a team on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your specific question in terms of code: A good idea would be to use the facade pattern to have a single point of access to the model from the controllers, so you can always call the facade and don't have to think about how his model logic will deal with the request internally, or which classes he will use. Furthermore, if MVC is done correctly the model, view and controllers will be swappable (as in, you could develop the view/controllers in javaFX but someone else can just use the same model and write android views/activities to call the logic). Meaning that you should not tell him what to provide from a controller point of view, but you should have your controller work with what the  model provides. Ofcourse, the model has to provide all the necesarry logic so here are some tips on how to achieve this in general.

To your question in general: If it's just you and a friend there are several things you can do to improve smooth development. Communication is important here, make sure you have predefined what you want to create and discuss some aspects of how this might be done.

Maybe create some user stories (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) or create a GUI mockup (each create a mockup, or you just create one) and discuss it. This will make you know what is required from a user point of view in the GUI, and he will see how your GUI handles this and will know which data will have to be provided by the model.

In addition you could try pair-programming, so he gets a feel for the view/controller code and you get a feel for the model code. Ofcourse you're not strictly developing apart anymore then, but rather together on some parts. Anyway, as it's only a two-man project and you both get along, this might be a fun and enriching experience.

Anyway, if you run into a problem where you think "Frick, I need this data but the facade doesn't expose it" you can just tell him that you need that bit of data and he can create a method in the facade that provides this. Sometimes requirements change or you have to do something you didn't think of before. That's software development though ^^

Comment: Glad you like them :) feel free to upvote or accept this answer to let other people whom have this question know it's a good answer :)

Comment: I cannot upvote yet, but accept ^^

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to develop the 2 aspects in different processes and use a form of IPC to communicate between the two. He will develop a "server" process that must define an API for you to use. (You don't have to use the client-server model like this so you could develop in 2 different linked modules, but it helps for testing and also helps to reuse the server components if you want to change the GUI to a web or mobile interface instead)

In any other form of doing what you want - ie 2 developers writing code in different, interlinking areas, the only sane way is to define the API regardless. Any other way will descend into a madness of chaotic developments where you continually break each others code.

Note that the API can continually evolve, often in response to your needs, but its usually a good idea to start with some form of design where you come up with a base from which to build on.

Comment: What does IPC bring to the table? Why not just host business logic in process? Why pay the price of IPC for no gain. I agree that defining interfaces is the right thing to do.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen too quick Mr Pedersen, check my edit. I'd say its a good idea for them as they will be developing in completely independent projects then, so they won't tread on each others toes. It also prevents 'quick hack workarounds'. They could develop in dlls, or just shared directories, but I think client-server is a good way to teach them the separation.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be using pure MVC and then defining an interface for the model? Because MVC is designed for being able to switch the UI.

Comment: I don't know. It seems to me IPC would bring additional complexity without any real benefit.

Comment: @Benjoyo When I say switch the UI, I mean switch the technology completely. You may develop a thick-client UI and then decide you want a web-based UI instead. Or you develop a Java Swing UI and then decide you want a C/OpenGL UI later.

Comment: @gbjbaanb when MVC is done right one should be able to switch from thick-client to web or even to console without a problem. Thats what I meant.

Comment: @Benjoyo not when its all done in a single process. I've seen MVC code turn monolithic very quickly, something that cannot happen with a set of independent processes. If you had to ask how to do this kind of development, then doing it in a way that forces independence will help you.

Comment: @gbjbaanb now I see what you were talking about :D